# When were bounties first introduced?

Tags: discussion, bounties

By looking at some relevant questions I can tell that bounties were introduced approximately 10 years ago, but does anyone remembers the exact date that bounties were introduced?
I took a look at the [bounty page in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) but there is no info about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bounties were introduced in January 2009.

Source: [Stack Overflow Blog: Reputation Bounty for Unanswered Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/27/reputation-bounty-for-unanswered-questions/)